# Understanding Spherical coordinates on ellipses.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I was given the following problem:

$$\iiint\limits_D (4x^2+9y^2+36z^2)\,dV,$$

where $V$ is the interior of the ellipsoid
$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}+z^2=1.$$

The problem gives what the new coordinate system will be:
\begin{align}
x&=3\rho\sin\theta\cos\phi,\\
y&=2\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi,\\
z&=\rho\cos\theta.
\end{align}

I don't really know why that would work. Let's take the ellipse on the $xy$ plane and polar coordinates:
$$\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1;~~~~~~~~~~~~x=3r\cos\theta,~~y=2r\sin\theta.$$
How do I know that for every $\theta$ I will end up with a point **on** the ellipse?

[image]

Moreover, how do I know that with the change of variables given by the problem I will end up with a point **on** the ellipsoid? I appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take $r=1$ in your case (where you made the change of variables to polar coordinates), you know for every $\theta$ you will be **on** the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1$ simply because for every $\theta$, the equation for that ellipse will be true.

$$
\begin{align*}
1&=\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}\\
&=\frac{\left(3\cos(\theta)\right)^2}{9}+\frac{\left(2\sin(\theta)\right)^2}{4}\\
&=\frac{9}{9}\cos^2(\theta)+\frac{4}{4}\sin^2(\theta)\\
&=\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\\
&=1
\end{align*}
$$

And if you vary $r$ (let $0\leq r<1$), you'll be inside that ellipse.

Comment: I don't know if this truly answered your question. Please tell me if (and how) it didn't.

Comment: I thought about it before posting the question, but weren't very sure about it. Now I see that it is actually a valid argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, one could try defining:
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{3}=u, && \frac{y}{2}=v.
\end{align}
Therefore
$$\iiint\limits_D (4x^2+9y^2+36z^2)\,dV=\iiint\limits_{D^*} (36u^2+36v^2+36z^2)6\,dV^*.$$
Now taking the spherical transformation:
$$216\iiint\limits_{D^{**}}\rho^4\sin\theta \,dV^{**} = \frac{864}{5}\pi.$$